# How to check cell output (and maybe also input) to match a correct solution - Using Python Notebooks for teaching

Tags: python, testing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbgrader

I recently saw something pretty cool on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/python). When you fill out and run cells in their tutorial notebooks you get pretty much like live feedback, if you did it right or not. I would love to be able to implement my own exercises this way, so that I can hand those notebooks out to my class and the students would get immediate feedback on their programming.

So far I seem to be unable to find how this is done or maybe I miss the right words to put into Google.
I found the [nbgrader](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but that isn't exactly what I was searching for.

Is there a way to do such evaluation directly in the notebooks, or does Kaggle probably use some other software in the backend to get this effect of direct evaluation?

Or can I maybe use unittests in some fashion to get such an effect?

Comment: [Gofer Grader](https://okgrade.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/) mentions [okpy](http://okpy.org).

Comment: That looks real nice - thanks @Wayne